# For given set $A$, show that there exist a set of 'every finite sequence on $A$'.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms

To be specific, I'll state some definitions first.

> 1. $0=\emptyset$
>      $1=\{\emptyset\}=\{0\}$
>      $2=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}=\{0,1\}$
>      ...
>      $n=\{0,1,2,....,n-1\}$
> 2. For given set $\text A$ and $\text B$,
>      $\text B^\text A=\{ f\in P(\text A \times \text B) $ | $ f:\text A \to \text B \}$
> 3. Any function $f:n\to \text{A} $ is finite sequence.
>      Any function $f:\mathbb N \to \text A$ is infinite sequence.

In terms of above definitions, $$\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb N} A^n $$
is set of every finite sequence on $A$.

I want to prove this set exists. If I prove  $J=\{\text A^0,\text A^1, \text A^2, ....\}$ exists, above set exsits by Axiom of union.

But I have no idea how to prove $J$ exists. I know each $\text A^n$ exist. but how can I construct such a big set?
I'm sure that I can't apply Axiom of pair infinitely many times.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what the *Axiom of Replacement* is for. Once you know $\mathbb N$ exists, the Axiom of Replacement guarantees that
$$ \{ A^i \mid i \in \mathbb N \} $$
is a set.

Answer (score 2):

Either use the **Axiom Schema of Replacement,**
$$J=\{\,A^n\mid n\in\Bbb N\,\} $$
Or note that all $A^n$ are subsets of $P(\Bbb N\times A)$ and use the **Axiom Schema of Separation** from there.